# Ubuntu login sound missing in GNOME Shell

Tags: sound, login, gnome

When I start GNOME Shell, the login sound of Ubuntu doesn't play.

I've tried to find the startup command of the sound on Google without any luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Download dconf editor if you haven't already. Then click in this order org -> gnome -> desktop -> sound. Once in sound, click on the theme name there (it says freedesktop if I'm not mistaken) and change it to ubuntu (lowercase!) and exit. Log out and log back in to hear the glorious drums :)